# JVM stops updating screen

Tags: kotlin, ubuntu, jvm, raspberry-pi4

I have a program that shows local weather, forecast, weather radar and some other things.
I've been tweaking it for a few years now. It's written in Kotlin and runs on JVM 17 on a Raspberry PI 4 with Ubuntu 22.04. The problem is that the screen stops updating at random times (hours, days, weeks) but the program runs just fine. I have to kill the whole process and restart to fix it.
I've had it in the (IntelliJ) debugger when it has stopped and as far as I can tell nothing is wrong. All the threads are running as they should, Graphics handles look fine and no errors. JVM just stops updating the screen.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I added logging to all paint functions and it stopped again at 15:55:38 today. Here's the log for around that instant (the radar does 10 fps)

```
15:55:37.652 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:37.753 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:37.854 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:37.956 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.057 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.147 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @clock.tick#30] TRACE - clock.paint
15:55:38.158 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.260 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.361 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.462 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.564 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.665 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.766 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.867 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:38.968 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:39.069 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:39.148 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @clock.tick#30] TRACE - clock.paint
15:55:39.170 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:39.271 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:39.372 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
15:55:39.473 [AWT-EventQueue-0 @radar.paint#14] TRACE - radar.paint
```

It keeps running even when the screen doesn't update.

EDIT2:
This is what the screen looks like
[image: small version of screen]

Comment: What's the UI - Browser/HTML, JavaFX, ... ?

Comment: It's a regular Java Swing/AWT window

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's > 10 years since I last worked on Swing, but I'd put money on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) has either died or got stuck in blocked state.

Think about what code you ever execute on this thread and wrap it with try/catch and error logging so you can spot if it fails and why.  Since you say you are showing data from weather forecasts, etc you must be making I/O calls off platform which could timeout/fail.

Or perhaps you have memory leak (another thing very possible in a long-running application like this) which you never reach on your IntelliJ testing, so you could close your eyes and implement the good old IT solution to everything... you proactively restart start the app nightly :-/

Comment: Good guess, but no. The Event Dispatch Thread is running and calling the paint functions as it should. The screen stopped updating a few minutes ago (after running for about 10 hours) and I just remote connected both JProfiler and IntelliJ debugger. Both tells me that the program (and Event Dispatch Thread) are running correctly.

Comment: OK, so your update process is off the Event Dispatch Thread - good.  Do you know that this is running normally? Can you log that?

Comment: I added log to the original question, didn't fit in a comment.

Comment: You mention "Radar ... 10 fps" ... are you playing a "movie" of rain radar plots over time?  If so, this is a more active screen than I had imagined.  My guess is that you have a memory leak.  Can you add into your logs a regular memory count of some sort? (https://www.baeldung.com/native-memory-tracking-in-jvm)

Comment: I added an screenshot of the app. The radar holds 5 hours of images (total 60 images) and plays continuously at 10 fps. The forecast at the bottom updates every 5 minutes.

Comment: I've evaluated the memory usage and it's not that either. I capped it at 500MB and it uses 240MB at minimum and GC jumps in at about 460MB to bring it back down.

Comment: Next ideas: what's changed recently might have caused this.  Have you brought in a new version of an external library?  Is the data supplied by your external source changed, structurally?  Does the freeze appear at the same time of day?  What else is happening on your local network prior to the freeze?

Answer (score 0):

For those that are interested...
I replaced the Raspberry Pi and the problem disappeared :-)